# Why does this keep returning #<procedure>?

Tags: scheme

The first makes into an interval, the second is supposed to car that interval.

```
(define make-interval
    (lambda (lower upper)(cons lower upper)))

(define lower-endpoint
    (lambda (interval)
      (lambda (lower upper)
        (car (interval lower upper)))))
```

Instead I keep getting procedure returned. It's probably a very simple fix, I don't see it! T.T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's causing the error is the fact that you're returning a procedure (the second `lambda` in `lower-endpoint`), not a value.

The second procedure only needs the `interval` as parameter, the second `lambda` is unnecessary, same thing for the `lower` and `upper` parameters: why ask for them, if the `interval` parameter already has them? This is what you intended:

```
(define lower-endpoint
  (lambda (interval)
      (car interval)))
```

You can use a simpler, equivalent syntax for procedure definition:

```
(define (lower-endpoint interval)
  (car interval))
```

Or even shorter, simply create an alias of `car`, because that's the only thing that `lower-endpoint` is doing:

```
(define lower-endpoint car)
```

Comment: That indeed fixed it! Thank you very much for the quick response!